# Is it possible to use Arquillian Graphene without using Arquillian container management and deployment?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone, graphene2

I have a quite big set of Selenium driven UI tests, that are very cumbersome to maintain. I've read about Arquillian Graphene and its benefits, making life with Selenium less painfull.

I wonder if it's possible to use Arquillian Graphene (2) without using the Arquillian framework underneath it, i.e. simply drive Selenium tests against a running application.
Do you have any experiences or are there any showstoppers from making this setup work?
Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the 'standalone' version will remove the Container/Deployment support.

The only problem is you'll also miss all the Container/Deployment metadata that Arquillian automatically fetch and use to e.g. construct the URL injection.

As of Graphene 2.1.0.Alpha2 there was added support to configure a URL in arquillian.xml if one was not provided automatically. Using that feature should allow you to use Graphene against an already deployed application as if it was deployed by Arquillian.

Essentially put this in your arquillian.xml file:

```
<arquillian>
  <extension name="graphene">
    <property name="url">http://localhost:8080/app/</property>
  </extension>
</arquillian>
```

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQGRA-374 for more details.

Comment: Thanks Aslak, I already use that approach and got it to work - I already had contact with other users and also the project lead of Graphene, Lukas, and afaik you're the project lead for Arquillian. 
I have to say you have a really helpful and supporting community, takk skal du ha to all the Arquillians.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer myself: yes, it is possible. But I'll have to reword the question a little bit: Is it possible to use Arquillian Graphene without using Arquillian container management.

What I do now is have a already deployed application inside its container, i.e. I do not use Arquillian to deploy all or part of the application, and I use Graphene 2 and Drone to drive my Selenium tests on that application.

The only documentation I found regarding this setup is https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQGRA2/Framework+Integration+Options

> Arquillian Mode Options
>   You can choose between following Arquillian modes
>
> Standalone
>   runs tests without container integration, only lifecycle of extensions is  managed
>   allows to use Graphene independently of Arquillian containers and  deployment management

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have been using it for the past 18 months in a standalone mode.

Please check here for more info.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automation-using-arquillian-framework/